# TLP install on 17.10 stuck with odd Mail Server Message

Tags: 17.10, tlp

I'm trying to install TLP on 17.10, following the usual instructions with sudo apt-get, et al. All is well until half-way through the process, I'm greeted with a graphics in the terminal with the header "Postfix Configuration" and a bunch of stuff about mail servers.

I'm totally new to linux and have no idea what's doing.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out: I needed to append the --no-install-recommends in apt-get.

Working now.